# best way to organize layout page, or multiple include views using one page

Tags: php, codeigniter

Which approach would you recommend me to use in building "Layout" or "Master" page in CodeIgniter.

Should I create master page view like this

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header"><?php include "_header.php"?>
    </div>
    <div id="content"><?php echo $content ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
       <?php include "_footer.php"?>
    </div>
</div>
```

_header.php

```
<?php echo $title ?>
```

and controller which sends data

```
function displayData()
{
   $data['title'] = "some title";
   $data['content'] = "content page";
   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('content', $data);
}
```

or you use some other technique, I'm coming from asp.net mvc world so I'm trying to grab fast as possible some tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter has a layout library. You can access it here 
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/layout-library.
 Also, you can approach layouts in Codeigniter using hooks.